# React Native Text is not getting bounded by limits of container View

Tags: typescript, react-native, textview, overflow, expo

I am creating a react native expo app. In it, I want to create a 2 column layout. Content's title on the left and data on the right.

```
<View>
  <Text>Some title</Text>
  <Text>Some pretty long content</Text>
<View>
```

So it should be displayed like:

```
*--------------------------*
| Some Title   Some pretty |
|              long content|
*--------------------------*
```

But right now what happens is:

```
*--------------------------*
| Some Title   Some pretty long
|              content     |
*--------------------------*
```

So text doesn't seem to take the width according to its parent's width.

This is how it looks:

[image: Screen shot of how text is overflowing]

The view hierarchy is this:

```
<View> -- 100% width 

  <View> -- Margin of 10 & padding of 5 & curved border

    <View> -- Flex row & a 1px border to show its expected width

       <Text>Title</Text>
       <Text>Content</Text> -- Overflowing text 

       <Text>Title</Text>
       <Text>Content</Text> -- Overflowing text 

       .
       .
       .

       <Text>Title</Text>
       <Text>Content</Text> -- Overflowing text 

    </View>

  </View>

</View>
```

I can add the CSS and TSX code if you want, but I have summarised the important bits above.

Comment: Add `{ flexWrap: "wrap" }` to View containing Text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flex wrap: wrap
Flex:1 
Set this to your text style sheets if View style is having flex direction as row.

Alternatively
try width as 100% for both parent View and texts.

Comment: Nope! Not helping.

Comment: Tried this again today. As long as only one child component of a parent view with flexDirection: "row" has flex: 1, then it correctly takes up space.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `width="100%"` to your `Text` component.

P.S: I should have asked this in comment but a new StackOverFlow user here.

Comment: Haha that's okay! I tired adding width="100%", but that did not help. Right now I cheated and did this: "" width: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width) - 120 ""